# How to get values with a for loop that checks another table's values?

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

This is pretty complicated so I didn't know how to make a title for this.

The following two tables are just examples of what I have. Table A has data that I want to be drawn in to Table B. So I'm trying to create a for loop and give wherever there is 'alex' in table B the values found in table A.

[image]

The values should be in the order they appear in the table A.

So I want Table B to become as such:

[image]

Comment: you talked about tables having pairs person-code where person isn't a unique key. Since you need a solution in VB.NET there's the need to add from scratch the logic to read and write those tables. Taken the conditions like you described, you are missing a field to give an order to the records. There's no logic to choose the order in your example. It would be nicer for who is going to answer to add just the algorithm on top of your solid context if you added it to your question.

Comment: I noted that the order in which the data appears is the order I want the data to be given in the second table. So, from top to bottom in Table A, that's the order I want the data to be given to Table B.

Comment: If you are intending to use a database to store the tables and their values then the first thing you need to look at is adding a unique identifier column to at least TableB. TableA has the potential to use the code column for this. Without a unique identifier, you will be unable to determine which person (abcd / alex) row to update the code for.
If you are working only with the data stored in objects such as arrays or collections for client UI display only, then you might be able to get away with a loop. But even then it will be a bit ugly without an initial unique identifier for TableB.

Comment: NB. The best way to work with data is to use Linq queries on data objects (loaded from a variety of data sources). But the loaded data must be in a compliant format.